# Como realizarlo con un array en PHP y Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Paso a explicar lo que intento hacer,

Tengo 2 tablas en mysql

Tabla 1: lista de productos

Ej:

| id | categoria |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | azul |
| 2 | azul |
| 3 | azul |
| 4 | azul |
| 5 | azul |

Tabla 2: producto elegido

| id | ident | categoria | usuario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | azul | argentina |
| 2 | 1 | azul | brasil |

Ahora bien,
Siguiendo el ejemplo de las tablas, para ARGENTINA quiero mostrar todos los productos excepto los que ya fueron elegidos. Osea, mostrar solo los que faltan por elegir.

Intenté crear un array de los registros de la tabla 1 para luego eliminarlos por otro array de la tabla 2, de ese modo me quedaria un array solo con los productos que quedan sin ser seleccionados.

Pero mi cabeza esta en blanco. Y eh perdido toda lógica.

Comment: Adjunta el código de lo que intentaste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intenté crear un array de los registros de la tabla 1 para luego
> eliminarlos por otro array de la tabla 2, de ese modo me quedaria un
> array solo con los productos que quedan sin ser seleccionados.

No hagas eso. No le tires a PHP un problema que debes resolver a nivel de la base de datos. Aprovechando por ejemplo los índices que habrás puesto en las tablas, que te ayudarán a filtrar adecuadamente los datos y obtenerlos con mayor fluidez, algo nada despreciable, sobre todo cuando tu base de datos crezca.

Asumiré que la columna que sirve para relacionar ambas tablas es la columna `id`. Con esta simple consulta obtendrías los productos que no han sido seleccionados por el usuario `argentina`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM lista_productos 
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM producto_elegido 
  WHERE usuario='argentina'
);
```

Ahora sólo tienes que trabajar con tus resultados.

Aquí tienes un fiddle, donde podrás hacer pruebas sobre los datos:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE lista_productos (
  id INT,
  categoria VARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO lista_productos (id,categoria) VALUES (1,'azul');

INSERT INTO lista_productos (id,categoria) VALUES (2,'azul');

INSERT INTO lista_productos (id,categoria) VALUES (3,'azul');

INSERT INTO lista_productos (id,categoria) VALUES (4,'azul');

INSERT INTO lista_productos (id,categoria) VALUES (5,'azul');

INSERT INTO lista_productos (id,categoria) VALUES (6,'rojo');


CREATE TABLE producto_elegido (
  id INT,
  ident INT,
  categoria VARCHAR(50),
  usuario VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO producto_elegido (id,ident,categoria,usuario) VALUES (1,1,'azul','argentina');

INSERT INTO producto_elegido (id,ident,categoria,usuario) VALUES (2,1,'azul','brasil');

INSERT INTO producto_elegido (id,ident,categoria,usuario) VALUES (3,1,'rojo','chile');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM lista_productos 
WHERE id NOT IN 
(
  SELECT id 
  FROM producto_elegido 
  WHERE usuario='argentina'
);
```

| id | categoria |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | azul |
| 3 | azul |
| 4 | azul |
| 5 | azul |
| 6 | rojo |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Hola!, me ha servido mucho tu respuesta, la verdad que me encontraba bloqueado, estoy dedicando bastante tiempo a este proyecto. Voy a ponerlo en práctica

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que el id de los productos en la tabla de elecciones sea `ident`, sería tan sencillo como obtenerlo desde MySQL con la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM productos
  WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ident FROM elecciones
  );
```

Si lo que tienes son dos arrays en PHP que has obtenido mapeando las tablas, sería algo así:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');

$productos = $conn->query("
        SELECT * FROM productos;
    ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$elecciones = $conn->query("
        SELECT * FROM elecciones;
    ")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($productos as $p)
    $productos_no_elegidos[$p['id']]=$p;
foreach($elecciones as $e)
    if(isset($productos_no_elegidos[$e['ident']]))
        unset($productos_no_elegidos[$e['ident']]);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($productos_no_elegidos,true).'</pre>';
```

Partiendo de un dataset así:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  categoria varchar(15)
  );
CREATE TABLE elecciones(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ident int,
  categoria varchar(15),
  usuario varchar(63)
  );
INSERT INTO productos (categoria) VALUES
  ('azul'),('azul'),('azul'),('azul'),('azul');
INSERT INTO elecciones (ident, categoria, usuario) VALUES
  (1,'azul','argentina'),
  (1,'azul','brasil');
```

Obtendrías, respectivamente, en MySQL:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | categoria |
+----+-----------+
|  2 | azul      |
|  3 | azul      |
|  4 | azul      |
|  5 | azul      |
+----+-----------+
```

Y, en PHP:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [categoria] => azul
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [categoria] => azul
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [categoria] => azul
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [categoria] => azul
        )

)
```

Recuerda que el primer paso siempre es intentarlo, puede que no te solucione el problema, pero al menos te saca del bloqueo en el que estés y ya te permite preguntar por algo más concreto.

Creo que el código es bastante autoexplicativo, si hay algo que no veas claro, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.